# Can we get Device Angle (Like compass) with 95-100 % accuracy?

Tags: android, android-sensors, compass

As you all know when compass come near magnetic field its value got disturbance and it went away from its actual value. I have been working on a project in which i have to get device rotation with 95% accuracy. I have tried number of sensors which can be used to get device angle but all have some sort of external factors which make it un-useful for me to use in my case.

For example when i use **TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD** and i came closer to any magnetic thing or electric wires or even my laptop its value adds up error.

when i use **TYPE_ORIENTATION** (i know its deprecated) its value adds up a Drift Value after some time which makes it unreliable for me to use.

I have also used some other sensors to combine and make it to behave like compass without magnetic field but all of them either become unreliable with magnetic field or adds up some drift after some time.

I have read some of research papers from difference research institutes but i don't think anyone has ever produce rotation angle with 95% accuracy. I want to know if there is any way even with AI algorithm from which we can achieve this case? The end goal is to get a device angle which is 95%> accurate.

Comment: With or without camera - i.e. ARCore or ARKit which would allow another reference to a static surface.

Comment: I need to use only sensors.

Comment: Unless you are able to predict & model the supplemental magnetic field, you are going to have a _really_ hard time.

Comment: Yes. True. Do you have any idea what is right methodology or algorithm for predicting the right angle even if the magnetic field jumps to 50% up ?

Comment: My thought is to model all of the sensors: compass, accelerometer, gyroscope and their respective drift/error (hard as it is temperature dependent and the datasheets from what I remember for the sensors are calibrated for a small temperature range). See: [Sensor Fusion on Android Devices: A Revolution in Motion Processing](https://youtu.be/C7JQ7Rpwn2k)